# Minimalist high speed 8051 microcontroller testing circuit on breadboard

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, crystal, debugging

I'm trying to come up with a circuit using the least number of parts possible to build on a breadboard that tests the basic functionality of a microcontroller, specifically the AT89LP4052 microcontroller.

This is what I have so far:

[image: circuit]

I omitted the coupling capacitors from the crystal because the speed I'm using is low and I think breadboards add capacitance.

I attempted to load the following hex data into the micro (so I think):

75h 90h 01h
   75h 90h 02h
   75h 90h 03h
   ...
   75h 90h 1Fh

What each line does is set the value of port 1 to the last value in the line. If programmed correctly, I should see at least both LED's blink at a high rate but none of them turn on, not even partially.

The interesting thing is when I was programming it, the micro had 12V on the reset line before any action, then I resetted everything and followed all op-codes as per instructions in the datasheet.

So before I can predict that the data entered into the micro is officially incorrect, is the circuit above good enough for minimal part count for proper testing to begin? or will I need to resort to adding a super low-speed oscillator (of say 2hz)?

Comment: Did you follow the power-up sequence as defined in 23.4.1? From your description it's not clear.
Are you controlling these lines with a programmer or are you using switches (I ask because of the minimalist mantra).  If you are using switches is the XTAL1 strobe switch debounced?

Comment: Clock has no function during programming so 2Hz won't make a difference there may help during code execution debug, did you make sure the pins were set to output mode?  Normal state on reset is input configuration.

Comment: This circuit is merely to test to see if the chip can execute correctly. I made a programmer but now I have a feeling I have to redo it because I didn't include pull-ups on all the parallel port pins

Comment: You need to define what you want to test. I often will include tests that validate the ALU, itself. Also, validate RAM, EEPROM, and other memories. (These have caught FAB problems [movement of production from one FAB to a different FAB] more than one time before.) I would also include tests for all the active peripherals (and this includes the bus interfacing unit, as well.) So I believe you really need to carefully specify what exactly you want to test in the device. That will have a lot to do with what is considered "minimalist."